Continuous paths of Gaussian processes on non-compact spaces
Suppose I want to define a Gaussian process on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with mean $\mu(x)$ and covariance $K(x,y)$ (positive semi-definite), where both $\mu$ and $K$ are $C^\infty$ (though not bounded) functions. I have read in textbooks that under these assumptions, the corresponding Gaussian process may be defined on compact sets such that with probability $1$, the sample paths are continuous. Of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. It seems reasonable to think that the same should hold for the whole real line by gluing countably many compact intervals. Is this right?
The difficulty I see is that what happens on different compact intervals is not independent of each other. Presumably you can condition on what happens on $[-n,n]$ and try to define the process on $[-n-1,n+1]$. However is the process still Gaussian if you do this conditioning? Certainly if you condition on what happens at finitely many points, the process is Gaussian, but I'm not sure about a whole continuum. I would appreciate any reference to a textbook that proves continuity for the case of $\mathbb{R}$.
